# how to define middleware only for certain paths in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-middleware

is there anyway to define middleware for specific route or route groups in django?
like laravel which we can define it as follows:

`Route::get('admin/profile', function () {})->middleware('auth');`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Historically there have been a few hooks you can exploit to do something like this. But nowadays you can for sure override:

```
def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
     ...
```

in your middleware class and then you could resolve the view/route from `request.path` and dispatch custom logic if it matches or not, or you could match over `view_func.__name__` or something similar, etc. Depends on your needs.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/#process-view