# How to apply path-based middleware in Django Channels?

Tags: django, django-channels

I currently have the problem, that I need different authentication mechanisms for different Django Channel consumers. One of them should use a custom token middleware while the other should use the standard session-based authentication. How can it be achieved that middlewares can be applied per path?

In the standard Django views this is achieved with `def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):` as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49614141/6783666).

```
# routing.py

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": get_asgi_application(),
        "websocket": TokenAuthMiddleware(
            URLRouter(
                [
                    path(
                        "ws-api/v1/farms/controllers/",
                        ControllerConsumer.as_asgi(),
                        name="ws-controller",
                    ),
                    path("ws-api/v1/graphql/", MyGraphqlWsConsumer.as_asgi()),
                ]
            )
        )
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in where two middleware "chains" are created and selected depending on the request path. It required that the `routing.py` and middlewares be modified as follows. The PathAuthMiddleware is responsible for selecting the chain of middlewares to be applied.

```
# routing.py

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": get_asgi_application(),
        "websocket": PathAuthMiddleware(
            URLRouter(
                [
                    path(
                        TokenAuthMiddleware.controller_ws_path,
                        ControllerConsumer.as_asgi(),
                        name="ws-controller",
                    ),
                    path(
                        "ws-api/v1/graphql/",
                        MyGraphqlWsConsumer.as_asgi(),
                        name="graphql-subscription",
                    ),
                ]
            )
        ),
    }
)
```

And the middleware responsible for the routing of the requests and the custom token authentication middleware.

```
# middleware.py

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack

class TokenAuthMiddleware:
    controller_ws_path = "ws-api/v1/farms/controllers/"

    def __init__(self, app):
         self.app = app

    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        ...
        return await self.app(scope, receive, send)

class PathAuthMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.controller_app = TokenAuthMiddleware(app)
        self.other_app = AuthMiddlewareStack(app)

    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        if scope["path"] == f"/{TokenAuthMiddleware.controller_ws_path}":
            return await self.controller_app(scope, receive, send)
        return await self.other_app(scope, receive, send)
```